# How do I serve an Angular application from existing nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an Angular 6 application and an existing nodejs api application. 
So far I have used

```
ng serve
```

to run and build the angular application.

I now want to serve my angular application from the existing node js server.

How do I do that ? I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Do `ng build`, It will create a dist folder which you can easily serve from node webserver framework like `express`, `Hapi` or `Koa`
2. if you are using express.js  you can server angular `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))`;
3. Now use node server URL to serve angular like `http://localhost:nodeport`

If you are using Hapi: check this out https://hapi.dev/tutorials/servingfiles/?lang=en_US

================================basic express server================

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");




//const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
//app.use(bodyParser.json());


//app.use('/api/v1/', require('./api/routes'));

 app.listen(8080,function(err){
   if(!err){
    console.log("server is running at port:8080);
   }
 })
```

Comment: This does not help during development. Moreover this is a very manual process. Is there any automated way to perform this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of serving an Angular SPA:

- **Usually dev**: the Webpack-run server, which is `ng serve`. Dynamic in the sense that any modification to a file starts a rebuild and updates the output.
- **Usually prod**: you build all the html/js files (with `ng build [...]`) for the SPA to be statically served by a `node` server.

In your case, if you'd like to use an existing `node` server, it means you'll have to build the files (with `ng build`) and then hook up the usual `node` static files serving snippet in your `node` app.

Beware though: you'll have to do a full build each time you want to update the display. So it's ok if it's not that often, but not ok for a dev environment I guess.